# How to terminate execution of API of specific request of specific client in Julia or Genie framework

Tags: request, julia, genie.jl

I have one API in Julia which done some calculation on input data and its time consuming process.

So multiple clients hits the request to one API at a time and a specific client wants terminate the execution of their request of API only , so how can I terminate or kill the execution of API of that particular client request only.

I try to kill the specific execution of task perform in API of particular specific request.